# Publication wrong date in google search result

Tags: angular, seo, google-news, google-ranking

I am working on Website developed by ANgular+Nojdejs. I work now especially on SEO. I noticed that my pages are displayed with the wrong dates in google search results.
I am using several structured data to communicate the right date to google but it is still wrong. I am also using google news (XML file with RSS FEED format).

Here is an example of what I am using in my code :

** JSON LD Example :**

```
"dateCreated": "2023-3-23T15:23:00+0000",
"datePublished": "2023-3-23T15:23:00+0000",
"dateModified": "2023-3-23T15:23:00+0000",
```

** Meta :**

```
<meta name="article:published_time" content="2023-3-23T15:23:00+0000">
<meta name="article:modified_time" content="2023-3-23T15:23:00+0000">
<meta name="itemprop:datePublished" content="2023-3-23T15:23:00+0000">
<meta name="itemprop:dateModified" content="2023-3-23T15:23:00+0000">
```

** XML File of RSS FEED**

```
<item>
     <pubDate>Thu, 23 Mar 2023 15:23:00 +0000</pubDate>
<item>
```

But it still displayed wrong in google when I search for the title of a new article with 8 hours shift between displayed date and publication date time. Have you any idea ?

Comment: "2023-3-23" should be "2023-03-23" although I don't see how that would lead to a wrong date, as opposed to a missing date.

Comment: thanks Stephen i will try this fix and i will give you feedback

Comment: these date data I see them in the source view Ctrl+U only in the article page (../single/) not in the Home page. I do not have this info in the main page of the website.

Comment: After adding  your fix and somes other parameters, it works for me : (0100 at the end)
`
  "inLanguage": "fr-FR",
  "dateCreated": "2023-03-24T17:07:00+0100",
  "datePublished": "2023-03-24T17:07:00+0100",
  "dateModified": "2023-03-24T17:07:00+0100",
`
Thank you

Comment: I think that you should post the corrected entries as your answer.  You are allowed to answer your own question.